# PyQt5: How to use closeEvent with a custom message-box

Tags: python, events, pyqt5, qdialog

Before I close my main window, I want to do some last operations.
I think the `closeEvent` is the right thing to do that, but the standard QMessageBox does not suit my design, so I want to make my own (and I did). But with the following code, the application closes directly without showing my message-box.

What here is the problem?

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    self.messageBox = lastWindow(self)
    self.messageBox.show()
    return super().closeEvent(event)
```

This is the `lastWindow` code: (subclass of a pyuic5 generated .ui file):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QGraphicsDropShadowEffect

from UIs.UI_quit import Ui_Quit

class lastWindow(QDialog, Ui_Quit):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(lastWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self._parent = parent
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
        self.shadow.setBlurRadius(10)
        self.shadow.setXOffset(5)
        self.shadow.setYOffset(5)
        self.shadow.setColor(QColor(0, 0, 0, 80))
        self.mainFrame.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)
        self.btn_close.clicked.connect(self.abort)
        self.btn_quit.clicked.connect(self.destroy)
        self.btn_abort.clicked.connect(self.abort)
        self._parent.blur.setEnabled(True)

    def destroy(self):
        self._parent.close()
        self.close()

    def abort(self):
        self._parent.startService()
        self.close()
```

Comment: "the standard QMessageBox do not fit in my layout": can you clarify what you mean with this? A message box is a top level widget, it shouldn't be shown in a layout. Also, please provide the code for `lastWindow` in the form of a [mre].

Comment: I mean it the Design of it. My layout is so cool and by closing the app, I want a nice looking message box. That's all. :-)

Comment: So what I need is to open a selfmade QDiaolog by clicking the red X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in [accept](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#accept) and [reject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#reject) slots to close the dialog, and then use the return value of [exec](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec) in your `closeEvent` to decide what to do next:

```
class lastWindow(QDialog, Ui_Quit):
    ...
    def destroy(self):
        self.accept()

    def abort(self):
        self.reject()
    
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    ...
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        dialog = lastWindow(self)
        if dialog.exec() == QDialog.Rejected:
            self.startService()
            event.ignore()
```

Calling `event.ignore()` will prevent the window closing; otherwise, the event will be accepted by default and the window will close. Note that, unlike `show()`, the `exec()` call blocks (i.e. it waits for user interaction), which explains why your current example doesn't work as you expected.